# Automatically use HTTPS

Tags: php, html, https, plesk

How do i get my website to use HTTPS when the user enters my domain, lets say they type www.mysite.com i want it to go to https://www.mysite.com.

Is there i way i can do this using plesk, or would it be fine in the index of the root folder was a page that redirects to https://www.mysite.com ? Or is there another way of setting it up so that it would automatically do that?

Thanks for the help people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your Webserver runs Apache, you can use modRewrite for that.

Add this to the `.htaccess`, that should be located in the root directory of the http domain

```
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT}   !^443$
RewriteRule     (.*)             https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1   [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'm a bit new to this so do you have any tutorials for that? Or tell me where that file should be? Thanks again.

Comment: Nice Tutorial with good Examples http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/ and http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples-2/

Comment: Better is to use `%{HTTPS}`, which will be `on` or `off` depending on if https is being used. It is possible to do https on ports OTHER than 443. But otherwise this is correct. +1

Comment: @ragebunny In Plesk (at least the versions I'm familiar with) you can add this to /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/conf/vhost.conf as an alternative to using a .htaccess (see http://www.gadberry.com/aaron/2006/02/09/plesk_vhost/ for more info).